# UNBUFFERED READWRITE with Win32 API in C++

Tags: c++, windows, writefile

I'm trying to make 150 bytes write in UNBEFFERED MODE (for test) but i miss something... if some one can help ?
the computed alignment sim to be right but still have a wrong data written data on the file...
the requirement are:
Size needed: 1024
Allocated pointer address at: DB6154D0
Allocated pointer address Aligned at: DB615600

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <string>

void DisplayError(LPTSTR lpszFunction);

// Macro Given by Microsoft for computing the closest even interval from the progam need.
#define ROUND_UP_SIZE(Value,Pow2) ((SIZE_T) ((((ULONG)(Value)) + (Pow2) - 1) & (~(((LONG)(Pow2)) - 1))))
#define ROUND_UP_PTR(Ptr,Pow2)  ((void *) ((((ULONG_PTR)(Ptr)) + (Pow2) - 1) & (~(((LONG_PTR)(Pow2)) - 1))))

// Config structure for Unbeffered IO.
struct HandleConfig {
    DWORD SectorsPerCluster;
    DWORD BytesPerSector;
    DWORD NumberOfFreeClusters;
    DWORD TotalNumberOfClusters;
};

void MesureDisk(HandleConfig* config, BOOL debug) {
    DWORD lpSectorsPerCluster;
    DWORD lpBytesPerSector;
    DWORD lpNumberOfFreeClusters;
    DWORD lpTotalNumberOfClusters;

    if (GetDiskFreeSpaceA(
        NULL,
        &lpSectorsPerCluster,
        &lpBytesPerSector,
        &lpNumberOfFreeClusters,
        &lpTotalNumberOfClusters)) {
        if (!debug) {
            std::cout << "Disk measure Ok.\r\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Disk measure Ok.\r\n";
            std::cout << "Disk Structure: " << "\r\n" <<
                "SectorsPerCluster: " << lpSectorsPerCluster << "\r\n" <<
                "lpBytesPerSector: " << lpBytesPerSector << "\r\n" <<
                "lpNumberOfFreeClusters: " << lpNumberOfFreeClusters << "\r\n" <<
                "lpTotalNumberOfClusters: " << lpTotalNumberOfClusters << "\r\n";
        }
    }
    config->SectorsPerCluster = lpSectorsPerCluster;
    config->BytesPerSector = lpBytesPerSector;
    config->NumberOfFreeClusters = lpNumberOfFreeClusters;
    config->TotalNumberOfClusters = lpTotalNumberOfClusters;
}

void Windows_write_UNBEFFERED() {
    // Config the handle. 
    HANDLE hFile;
    char DataBuffer[] = "Some data for test !\r\n";
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = 150;//(DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    LPCSTR filePath = "File.txt";  // File PATH.

    hFile = CreateFileA(
        filePath,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        OPEN_ALWAYS,
        FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, //Set Flag
        NULL
    );

    // Measure the disc.
    HandleConfig fileConf;
    MesureDisk(&fileConf, TRUE);//Display the struct on Terminal.

    // Ensure you have one more sector than WRITE_SIZE would require.
    size_t sizeNeeded = fileConf.BytesPerSector + ROUND_UP_SIZE(dwBytesToWrite, fileConf.BytesPerSector);
    char* Buffer = new char[sizeNeeded];            //heap Allocation
    void* BufferAligned = ROUND_UP_PTR(Buffer, fileConf.BytesPerSector); //Offset the allocated Pointer from the disk Nomenclature.
    
    printf("sizeneeded: %d \r\n", sizeNeeded);
    printf("Allocated pointer address at: %X \r\n",Buffer );
    printf("Allocated pointer address Aligned at: %X \r\n", BufferAligned);
    
    // void* BU = VirtualAlloc(NULL, dwBytesToWrite, MEM_COMMIT,PAGE_READWRITE);
    if (!WriteFile(
        hFile,
        BufferAligned,
        sizeNeeded,                                 
        &dwBytesWritten,
        NULL)) {
        DWORD message = GetLastError();
        DisplayError((LPTSTR)&message);
        delete[] Buffer;
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return;
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
    // VirtualFree(BU, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    delete[] Buffer;
}

int main() {
    Windows_write_UNBEFFERED();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void DisplayError(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
// Routine Description:
// Retrieve and output the system error message for the last-error code
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf =
        (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
            (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)
                + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)
                + 40) // account for format string
            * sizeof(TCHAR));

    if (FAILED(StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error code %d as follows:\n%s"),
        lpszFunction,
        dw,
        lpMsgBuf)))
    {
        printf("FATAL ERROR: Unable to output error code.\n");
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("ERROR: %s\n"), (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

I'm trying to write 150 bytes in UNBEFFERED mode on windows with WriteFile() into a simple file but something is missing this code compile but produce a file with wrong content.

Comment: Based on the final sentence, I think you misunderstood what the wizard meant by "what are you expecting.  It''s not the best wording, unfortunately, but what they want to you do is describe what you expected to happen, the desired output of the program, versus what you actually got. Any error message? Any diagnostics? Corrupt data? Outright crash?  Sometimes just comparing the expected with the observed is enough to shake the brain cells holding the answer loose, and if it doesn't make any sense to you, it usually does to one of us out here.

Comment: side note: consider replacing `char* Buffer = new char[sizeNeeded];`with `std::vector<char> buffer(sizeNeeded);` It sucks to have something like an exception prevent the program from reaching the `delete[] Buffer;` and leak it.

Comment: After `WriteFile` files, you should immediately call `GetLastError` (storing the result in a variable) and then print out the error code it returns.  That should tell you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strsafe.h>
#include <string>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono;
void DisplayError(LPTSTR lpszFunction);

// Macro Given by Microsoft for computing the closest even interval from the progam need.
#define ROUND_UP_SIZE(Value,Pow2) ((SIZE_T) ((((ULONG)(Value)) + (Pow2) - 1) & (~(((LONG)(Pow2)) - 1))))
#define ROUND_UP_PTR(Ptr,Pow2)  ((void *) ((((ULONG_PTR)(Ptr)) + (Pow2) - 1) & (~(((LONG_PTR)(Pow2)) - 1))))

// Config structure for Unbeffered IO.
struct HandleConfig {
    DWORD SectorsPerCluster;
    DWORD BytesPerSector;
    DWORD NumberOfFreeClusters;
    DWORD TotalNumberOfClusters;
};

void MesureDisk(HandleConfig* config, BOOL debug) {
    DWORD lpSectorsPerCluster;
    DWORD lpBytesPerSector;
    DWORD lpNumberOfFreeClusters;
    DWORD lpTotalNumberOfClusters;

    if (GetDiskFreeSpaceA(
        NULL,
        &lpSectorsPerCluster,
        &lpBytesPerSector,
        &lpNumberOfFreeClusters,
        &lpTotalNumberOfClusters)) {
        if (!debug) {
            std::cout << "Disk measure Ok.\r\n";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Disk measure Ok.\r\n";
            std::cout << "Disk Structure: " << "\r\n" <<
                "SectorsPerCluster: " << lpSectorsPerCluster << "\r\n" <<
                "lpBytesPerSector: " << lpBytesPerSector << "\r\n" <<
                "lpNumberOfFreeClusters: " << lpNumberOfFreeClusters << "\r\n" <<
                "lpTotalNumberOfClusters: " << lpTotalNumberOfClusters << "\r\n";
        }
    }
    config->SectorsPerCluster = lpSectorsPerCluster;
    config->BytesPerSector = lpBytesPerSector;
    config->NumberOfFreeClusters = lpNumberOfFreeClusters;
    config->TotalNumberOfClusters = lpTotalNumberOfClusters;
}

void Windows_write_UNBEFFERED() {
    
    //Set the Data.
    std::string date = std::format("Date: {:%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Z %Y}", zoned_time{ "Europe/Paris",floor<std::chrono::seconds>(system_clock::now()) });
    char DataBuffer[1024] = { "\0" };
    //Quick mem copy.
    size_t ct = 0;
    while (date[ct] != '\0') {
        DataBuffer[ct] = date.data()[ct];
        ct++;
    }

    // Config the handle. 
    HANDLE hFile;
    DWORD dwBytesToWrite = (DWORD)strlen(DataBuffer);
    DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0;
    LPCWSTR filePath = L"File.txt";  // File PATH.
    //Create File
    hFile = CreateFileW(
        filePath,
        GENERIC_WRITE,
        FILE_SHARE_READ,
        NULL,
        CREATE_ALWAYS,
        FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, //Set Flag
        NULL
    );

    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        DWORD message = GetLastError();
        DisplayError((LPTSTR)&message);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return;
    }

    // Measure the disc.
    HandleConfig fileConf;
    MesureDisk(&fileConf, TRUE);//Display the struct on Terminal.

    // Ensure you have one more sector than WRITE_SIZE would require.
    const size_t sizeNeeded = fileConf.BytesPerSector + ROUND_UP_SIZE(dwBytesToWrite, fileConf.BytesPerSector);


    //Print Current Buffer Adress and offset Constraints for UNBEFFERED IO.
    printf("size needed: %d \r\n", sizeNeeded);

    // Move the current file pointer in Constreined offset (test for control ...neutral modification... or write in the midle of the block).
    printf("Current pointer position A: 0x%X \r\n", SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_CURRENT));
    if (SetFilePointer(hFile, 0x200, 0, FILE_BEGIN) == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER) {//Move 512 bytes forward.
        DWORD message = GetLastError();
        DisplayError((LPTSTR)&message);
        printf("ERROR on Set file pointer...\r\n");
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return;
    }
    printf("Current pointer position B: 0x%X \r\n", SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_CURRENT));
//  printf("Current pointer position C (reset at the begening of file): 0x%X \r\n", SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_BEGIN));

    // Write the file.
    if (!WriteFile(
        hFile,
        DataBuffer,
        sizeNeeded,
        &dwBytesWritten,
        NULL)) {
        DWORD message = GetLastError();
        DisplayError((LPTSTR)&message);
        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return;
    }
    CloseHandle(hFile);
}

int main() {
    Windows_write_UNBEFFERED();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void DisplayError(LPTSTR lpszFunction)
// Routine Description:
// Retrieve and output the system error message for the last-error code
{
    LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
    LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
    DWORD dw = GetLastError();

    FormatMessage(
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
        FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
        NULL,
        dw,
        MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
        (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
        0,
        NULL);

    lpDisplayBuf =
        (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
            (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf)
                + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction)
                + 40) // account for format string
            * sizeof(TCHAR));

    if (FAILED(StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
        LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
        TEXT("%s failed with error code %d as follows:\n%s"),
        lpszFunction,
        dw,
        lpMsgBuf)))
    {
        printf("FATAL ERROR: Unable to output error code.\n");
    }

    _tprintf(TEXT("ERROR: %s\n"), (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf);

    LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
    LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
}
```

Comment: Good that you have provided your won answer, but to make it a good answer that can help future askers with a similar problem, you need to clearly explain what the problem was and how the changes you made to the code solve the problem.